# can't get value from input fields in bootstrap modal on a jquery post call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to get the value of a couple of fields in a bootstrap modal and then have them sent via $.post call to a php script that sends an email and responds true if the email has been correctly sent or false otherwise.

I can't get those values...fields are always sent empty (or with the default value in case of a "select". I do not understand why. I ahve also tried to have the fields and the $.post call instantiated on modal show (sho.bs.modal), but nothing changes.

Here is my code...any hint?

**HTML**

*SELECTOR*

```
<select name="stato" data-recordid="1469" data-recordcustomername="John Snow" data-recordcustomerid="416" data-recordmailuser="info@ccustmeremail.com" class="statuschanger form-control" required="">
    <option value="">Choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Working on</option>
    <option value="2">Ready</option>
    <option value="3" selected="">Shipped with courier</option>
    <option value="4">Delivered</option>
</select>
```

*MODAL*

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="modaleSent" tabindex="10" role="dialog" data-focus-on="input:first" style="display: none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Invio messaggio di Tracking</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">    
                    <div id="modaleSentContent">    
                        <div id="nomeCliente" class="blocchiModale"></div>
                        <div id="emailCliente" class="blocchiModale"></div>
                        <div id="ordineCliente" class="blocchiModale"></div>
                        <div id="formTracking" class="blocchiModale">
                            <form id="sendtrack">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="track">Tracking number:</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="track" name="track">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="corrieri">Choose courier:</label>
                                    <select class="form-control" id="corrieri" name="corrieri">
                                        <option value="brt">BRT</option>
                                        <option value="dhl">DHL</option>
                                        <option value="sda">SDA</option>
                                        <option value="tnt">TNT</option>
                                        <option value="ups">UPS</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" value="" name="cliente" id="hcliente">
                                <input type="hidden" value="" name="ordine" id="hordine">
                                <input type="hidden" value="" name="emailcliente" id="hemailcliente">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="sendtrackbtn">Invia ora</button>
                            </form>                                 
                        </div>

                        <div id="sentmsg" class="blocchiModale"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info iscriviti" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
                $('#tblOrders').on('change', '.statuschanger', function(){

                var record = $(this).attr('data-recordid');
                var cliente = $(this).attr('data-recordcustomername');
                var email = $(this).attr('data-recordmailuser');
                var clienteid = $(this).attr('data-recordcustomerid');
                var ostatus = $(this).val();
                var cella = $(this).parent().parent();

                console.log('Updated record: '+record);

                $.post(
                "order_status.php",
                {
                    id:record,
                    stato:ostatus
                },
                function(data,status)
                {
                    if(data)
                    {   
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data.esito == 1)
                        {
                            // $("#msgcontainer").html('<div class="alert alert-success">Operazione correttamente eseguita!</div><hr>');

                            console.log('Record aggiornato corretamente! ID: '+record);

                            var originalcolor = cella.css("background");
                            cella.css("background", "#449D44");
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                cella.css("background", originalcolor);
                            }, 1000);
                            //console.log(cella.attr('class'));


                            if(ostatus == 3)
                            {
                                console.log('dovrebbe aprire una modale');

                                $("#modaleSentContent").find("#nomeCliente").html('<strong>Cliente</strong>: '+cliente);
                                $("#modaleSentContent").find("#hcliente").val(cliente);
                                $("#modaleSentContent").find("#emailCliente").html('<strong>Email</strong>: '+email);
                                $("#modaleSentContent").find("#hemailcliente").val(email);
                                $("#modaleSentContent").find("#ordineCliente").html('<strong>Ordine</strong>: '+record);
                                $("#modaleSentContent").find("#hordine").val(record);

                                $("#modaleSentContent").find("#sentmsg").html();
                                //$('#modaleSent').modal('show');


                                $('#modaleSent').on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) {

                                var trackno = $("#modaleSent #track").val().trim();
                                var courier = $("#modaleSent #corrieri").val();




                                $("#sendtrackbtn").on('click',function(e){
                                    e.preventDefault();

                                    $.post(
                                    "send_track.php",
                                    {
                                        oemail:email,
                                        oname:cliente,
                                        orecord:record,
                                        ocourier:courier,
                                        oclienteid:clienteid,
                                        otrack:trackno
                                    },
                                    function(data,status)
                                    {
                                        if(data.esito !== false)
                                        {
                                            $("#modaleSentContent").find("#sentmsg").html('Messaggio inviato correttamente');
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $("#modaleSentContent").find("#sentmsg").html('Si è verificato un problema con l\'invio');
                                        }

                                        //$("#modaleSentContent").find("#sentmsg").html(data.msg);
                                    },
                                    "json");

                                });

                                }).modal();

                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            $("#msgcontainer").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Operazione non eseguita!</div><hr>');
                            alert('Record NON aggiornato. ID: '+record);

                        }
                    }
                },
                "json");

            });
```

I have prepared a fiddle, even though the $.post calls to the php files have been changed to the echo/json/ path shown on Jsfiddle documentation.

Here is the [**link**](https://jsfiddle.net/148ar3vy/)

Thank you

Comment: If you look at the network tab in your inspector, you will see that the values are submitted properly. The problem might be in your PHP code, mind showing us what you have?

Comment: @ChinLeung the fields are transported to the PHP file, but the #track field and the #corrieri field are empty or set to the default value (in case of the select). So the problem is BEFORE arriving to the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have missed to add `id` in your table `id="tblOrders"`. So add `id` for your `table` and try. Here is the working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elumalaiit/148ar3vy/4/).

**UPDATE:**

You are assigning values for `trackno` and `courier` on modal shown itself. This means after modal shown values remains empty before clicking modal submit button.

So to get updated value assign your `courier` and `trackno` number values inside `$("#sendtrackbtn").on('click',function(e){});` like below

```
 $('#modaleSent').on("shown.bs.modal", function (e) {
    $("#sendtrackbtn").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var trackno = $("#modaleSent #track").val().trim();
        var courier = $("#modaleSent #corrieri").val();
        $.post("/echo/json/", {
            oemail:email,
            oname:cliente,
            orecord:record,
            ocourier:courier,
            oclienteid:clienteid,
            otrack:trackno
        },
        function(data,status)
        {
            if(data.esito !== false)
            {
                $("#modaleSentContent").find("#sentmsg").html('Messaggio inviato correttamente');
            }
            else{
                $("#modaleSentContent").find("#sentmsg").html('Si è verificato un problema con l\'invio');
            }

            //$("#modaleSentContent").find("#sentmsg").html(data.msg);
        }, "json");
    });
}).modal('show');
```

Here is the updated working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/148ar3vy/28/). Hope this will helps you!

Comment: Yes, I didn't add the id...sorry...but that's not the point. As you can see I have 2 $.post calls. The first one is working properly, the second one (which uses the input field and select box in the modal) doesn't. I was asking for that.

Comment: @Aptivus - Please see the updated the answer. Hope that will helps you!